# nginx, passenger only showing root page, all other routes fail

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

Nginx + passenger is only showing the root page / path, all other routes fail with 404 Not Found.
I know nginx and passenger must be running to correctly bring up the root path. Here's the entry for sites-available:

```
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name staging.redacted.com; # Replace this with your site's domain.

      passenger_enabled on;
      passenger_app_env staging;

      keepalive_timeout 300;

      client_max_body_size 4G;

      root /var/www/staging.redacted.com/current/public; # Set this to the public folder location of your Rails application.

      #try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }
```

routes.rb - even though they all work and pass their specs.

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      resources :users

      resources :brand_api_keys

      resources :ir_service_buckets
      resources :ir_service_images
      resources :ir_services do
        resources :ir_service_buckets do
          resources :ir_service_images
        end
      end
      resources :devices do
        resources :scans
      end
      resources :images do
        resources :scans
      end
      resources :campaigns do
        resources :images
      end
      resources :agent_brands
      resources :brands do
        resources :brand_api_keys
        resources :ir_service_buckets do
          resources :ir_service_images
        end
        resources :agent_brands
        resources :campaigns
      end
      resources :agents do
        resources :brand_api_keys
        resources :agent_brands
      end

      root 'agents#index'
    end
```

Comment: Please, attach your routes.rb file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try removing `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`
Remove or comment out the `try_files` line completely and it will work.

Comment: Moving `try_files` to a `location` block didn't help, it wasn't even showing the root path like that. I'm not getting any errors in either the the nginx or app logs.

Comment: Provide us an `access.log` entry about accessing URL which works and which isn't working please.

Comment: I've read about passenger a little — could you please test with "try_files" removed completly?

Comment: It worked! without any `try_files` it works perfectly! thanks so much, very appreciated. Please create an answer so i can accept it! :)

Comment: This is an old answer but man you saved me a bunch of headache!